# Composition of three right derived functors

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, derived-functors, derived-categories

The following theorem about composition of two derived functors is well known, see e.g. [[Stacks Project, Tag 015M]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/015M):

> Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ be abelian categories. Let
>   $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ and $G : \mathcal{B} \to
> \mathcal{C}$ be left exact functors. If $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$
>   have enough injectives, then the canonical map
>   $ R(G \circ F) \rightarrow RG \circ RF $ is an isomorphism of
>   functors from $D^{+}(\mathcal{A})$ to $D^{+}(\mathcal{C})$ if (and only if) $F(I)$ is $G$-acyclic for each
>   injective object $I$ of $\mathcal{A}$.

My question is about the situation with three such functors:

> Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ be abelian categories. Let
>   $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, $G : \mathcal{B} \to
> \mathcal{C}$, and $H : \mathcal{C} \to
> \mathcal{D}$ be left exact functors. Assume $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{C}$
>   have enough injectives, $F(I)$ is $G$-acyclic for each
>   injective object $I$ of $\mathcal{A}$, and $G(J)$ is $H$-acyclic for each
>   injective object $J$ of $\mathcal{B}$.
>
> Can we say something about the relation between
>   $ R(H \circ G \circ F)$, $ RH \circ R(G \circ F)$, $ R(H \circ G) \circ RF$, and $RH \circ RG \circ RF$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get full associativity, your assumptions are not enough. You need to assume something stronger about $F$ - it should map injectives to $H \circ G$-acyclics or something similiar.

To see that such a condition is necessary, consider the case where $G$ is the identity functor - your assumptions then give you back the first case, but without any assumptions on $F$. As you already have remarked, this is not enough to guarantee $R(H \circ G \circ F) \cong R(H \circ G) \circ RF$.

On the other hand, if you assume that $F$ sends injectives to $H \circ G$-acyclics, then two times applying your first box gives $R(H \circ G \circ F) \cong RH \circ RG \circ RF$.

Comment: Thanks for the example with the identity functor. This of course directly shows that there is no such theorem I wanted.